# AppUpdateInfo.clientVersionStalenessDays() returns large value

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-core

In the documentation for [AppUpdateInfo.clientVersionStalenessDays()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/appupdate/AppUpdateInfo.html#clientVersionStalenessDays()) it states:

> If an update is available or in progress, this method returns the
> number of days since the Google Play Store app on the user's device
> has learnt about an available update.

I was expecting this to return a `0` because it has only been a few hours since I created a new update; and if it had been tomorrow (or maybe 24 hours) it would increment to `1` and so on...

I am currently using the internal test track, and the value returned from this method is `19122`, even though I uploaded the latest release just a few hours ago.

I'm not entirely sure how to use this value as a result...

- Is the documentation incorrect?
- Could it be unreliable in certain test tracks? (I'm currently using internal)
- If not either of the above, how should this method be used?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in our production apps. I've raised an issue in the Issue Tracker. Please star the issue, if you are facing the same https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232516753